# Get the path of the notebook on Google Colab

Tags: path, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use [hyperas](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) (hyperparameter optimization for keras) in a [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com/) notebook, I've installed hyperas sucefully with:

```
!pip install hyperas
```

but there is a problem with the *minimize* function parameter *notebook_name* that is mandatory to set when you are using a notebook

This param has to be filled with the path of the  notebook but in Colab I don't know how to get it

Comment: Have you tried to type in the notebook name directly? I think colab should be running in the directory where the jupyter notebook is in.

Comment: yes, I tried and it didn't work :(   It says FileNotFoundError, I'd need the whole path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the `notebook.ipybn` from Google Drive. Then `hyperas` can extract the info from it.

```
# Install the PyDrive wrapper & import libraries.
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Copy/download the file
fid = drive.ListFile({'q':"title='notebook.ipynb'"}).GetList()[0]['id']
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': fid})
f.GetContentFile('notebook.ipynb')
```

Comment: Fantastic!  it's working like this, Thanks a lot for your  answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not work for me. Here is my solution. The directory assigned by colab is /content/. You need to download the current notebook from google drive and upload it to /content/.

Comment: It is not good solution. I tried it before for geckodriver.exe and it didn't worked.