# Find files in google colab

Tags: path, google-colaboratory

The following snippet in my google colab:

```
import sys
import os

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/MBA/MBA_USP/03_Modulo_Solucoes/16_Metologia_Pesquisa_Projeto_Conclusao/TCC'
fnames = os.listdir(path)
```

prints my files and directories:

```
['TCC', 'degree_dist.eps', 'mind_dataset']
```

Now I'd like to search for files starting from the above path, like so:

```
if os.path.exists('mind_dataset/file.csv'):
    try:
        # do something
```

---

But this is not finding `file.csv`, which is there. How do I append or join paths to my present path in colab, in order to find any file?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear

Comment: what is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

This seem related to setting up a [relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314294/relative-path-in-google-drive-mounted-in-google-colab) for Google Colab environment.

One way of doing so is by setting up a relative path to the desired folder before running any code (or just putting the absolute path)

```
%cd <path of parent directory>
   
if os.path.exists('mind_dataset/file.csv'):
    try:
        # do something
```

When running `drive.mount('/content/drive')` the environment path is `/content` but you can navigate to others existing directories

```
%pwd               # prints out the current environment path
os.listdir('.')    # list all files and folder in the current environment
%cd <desired path> # sets up a relative path
```

this works for both a local jupyter notebook or a Google Colab one