# What is the command to read the whole path of a Google Colab notebook?

Tags: python, get, google-colaboratory

**Hi there,**

with the python code below I am able to read the file name of the current Google Colab notebook automatically. I now would like to read the whole path of the notebook including (or excluding) the file name. Anyone can help?

**Thanks in advance!!**

In:

```
from requests import get
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname
ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()) # 172.28.0.12
filename = get(f"http://{ip}:9000/api/sessions").json()[0]["name"]
print(filename)
```

Out:

```
NotebookTest.ipynb
```

The desired result should be the whole path like

```
"My Drive/Colab Notebooks/NotebookTest.ipynb"
```

The output of `"My Drive/Colab Notebooks"` would also be okay.

I tried out changing "name" to "path" in the get-command, but the result gives me something unusable.

Solution at [Get the path of the notebook on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920031/get-the-path-of-the-notebook-on-google-colab) doesn't work for me, as I wish to adapt it to the code indicated above.

Comment: i like this question as i had been trying to do similar. I think that colab files need google permissions for security purposes.

Comment: Then I hope we get a solution on this, please upvote question. Thanks.